# Multi-threading in CBC solver [or-tools]

Tags: or-tools, coin-or-cbc

I am CBC solver and or-tools in the python environment(ubuntu server). I have installed or-tools through pip. Is there a way to enable multi-process/thread for the solver to speed up the solving process? Do I need to build the CBC solver separately with different configuration?

I tried setting the number of threads using SetNumThreads method on OR-Tools but did not result in any change in performance.

Answer (score 1):

We ship OR-tools with a CBC/CLP/OSI/CGL/CoinUtils built in mono-thread since we never managed to have a robust (no dead lock, ub, consistent result) multi-threaded CMake based build version.

PR welcome to fix my CMake fork: https://github.com/mizux/cbc